# RewriteRule not working if file doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a RewriteRule in my .htaccess-file, really easy like
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/styles/thumb-75/(.*) $1/styles/thumb-150/$2`
But it only redirects the user if the "thumb-150"-file exists. But I would like to always redirect the user over there, as the file will be created on request.
Is there any option to set for the Rule, so that it doesn't check for the destination file to exist?

Comment: Is that the only rule/condition in your htaccess file?

Comment: No, there are a lot of rules as I'm using a Drupal CMS. There are these additional rules before the statement mentioned above:
`RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]`
`RewriteBase /`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico`
`RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Comment: Please edit your post, and add the entire htaccess.